# Start Vertica database during boot on Linux

Tags: vertica

I have Vertica installed in an Ubuntu virtual machine and I'd like to have a specific database started during the boot, instead of me having to login, open admintools and start from there.

So, is there a  command line that would allow me to start it without user interaction?
In which run level should I add this?
Also, I use a specific user to run everything Vertica related, does this need to be taken into account in my boot script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just set the restart policy(reboot on boot) in your admintools "Set Restart Policy"
You have 3 option :
 Never
 ksafe
 always -- chose this one to start on boot.

And that is it !
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this method as it *only* helps when the database is up and is K-safe. The best approach is to append `admintools -t start_db ...` to the startup.

Comment: valid approach as well.

Answer (score 6):

admintools -t start_db

```
[dbadmin@hostname ~]$ admintools -t start_db --help
Usage: start_db [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d DB, --database=DB  Name of database to be started
  -p DBPASSWORD, --password=DBPASSWORD
                        Database password in single quotes
  -i, --noprompts       do not stop and wait for user input(default false)
  -F, --force           force the database to start at an epoch before data
                        consistency problems were detected.
```

Comment: Ok, I added that to /etc/rc.local inside a su command. A bit ugly because I can see the output on my login screen, but that will do.